# Get data from a json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to save "title" value from

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=usa&redirects=true
```

I use this code but doesn't work:

```
string fileDownload;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    fileDownload = client.DownloadString("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=usa&redirects=true");
}
JObject sa = JObject.Parse(fileDownload);

string sq = sa["query"]["pages"][0]["title"].ToString();
```

I use `[0]` after `["pages"]` because pageid changes for another page.

Comment: `["query"]["pages"][0]` does not have an element `title` -- pages is NOT an array but a hash.  It's `["query"]["pages"][<page id>]["title"]`  You could use `["query"]["pages"].keys` to get the set of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
string sq = sa["query"]["pages"].First.First["title"].ToString();
```